# Embedding video file only on my site

Tags: html, web, youtube, social-networking

I hope that my question will be clear to understand.

I have some videos and I want to embed them on my website. YouTube is perfect place for them, but there is one problem - I just want to make that these videos will be able to watch only at my website - nowhere else. Private video function drops out - it is not a solution.

Is there any possibility to do that? I heard that Vimeo can do that, but how it works?

Payable solutions I will also consider.

Regards

Comment: have you tried using <embed> on your website? It is used to embed mutlimedia type objects into your website, and it doesn't require much.

Comment: but I have .avi files, mp4, mpeg4 etc. I need some place like youtube or vimeo to storage it

Comment: please explain to me what you're trying to do again? I am confused on what you're asking.

Comment: Why is it important that people watch only at your website?

Comment: because these videos are education materials made by me. Users will get ability to watch them after paid a subscription, only at my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On YouTube you can make the video [unlisted](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177)

> Making a video unlisted means that only people who have the link to the video can view it. Unlisted videos won’t appear in any of YouTube's public spaces, like your channel, search results, or the homepage.

This might not be what you want if you are planning on selling subscriptions for the videos. It seems vimeo might have what you are looking for (you'll need a [pro account](http://vimeo.com/pro) ) .
Have a look at [this discussion.](http://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:31238) It's old but might set you on the right path.

Comment: I see now that also Plus account have this option (Domain Level Privacy). Thanks! Can you tell me, what kind of video file types (avi or maybe mp4) I'm able to upload on vimeo? Regards!

Comment: see this [page](http://vimeo.com/help/faq#what_types_of_video_files_does_vimeo_allow). I'm using my phone and can't view that page.

Comment: @whoah with regards to the type of account, [this section](http://vimeo.com/help/faq/pro#vs_plus) of the faq states in its last sentence `Vimeo Plus is intended for individuals who want more features than a Basic (free) account, however Vimeo Plus users may not upload videos that are commercial in nature, or that are intended to sell or promote a product or service.`